# Default value in input does not work when using ngModel

Tags: angular

I'm trying to add paging to my pdf viewer in angular and I have the following code:

```
<input value="1" type="number" min="1" max="{{ totalPages }}" [(ngModel)]="page">/{{ totalPages }}
```

I want to set the default value of the input to be "1", but this does not work. If I take out

```
[(ngModel)]="page"
```

then it work perfectly fine. What is the cause of this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The input gets bound to the value of `page` and thus, the default `value=1`gets overriden. But `page` is probably empty / not inialized in your component, so the value is just blank. You need to initialize your `page` with 1 in your component e.g. like so:

`page: number = 1`

Then, you can also get rid of the `value=1` initialization within the template.

Comment: Thank you so much!